Apache2 - Cache-Control configured twice
I have tested an Apache2 with testssl and was informed that Cache-Control should be configured twice.
I was able to confirm the same in another test.
It is an Apache2 2.4
On the one hand, the old option Pragma: no-cache is active - but not set in any .conf - and on the other hand Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate.
However, I have configured Header set Cache-Control "max-age=63072000, public" in the conf of the vHost.
I would like to ensure that only the option I have defined is active:
Header set Cache-Control “max-age=63072000, public”
